# Portfolio and Risk Management: Total Return Index vs Price Index

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management, benchmark, indexes

For portfolio construction and risk management purposes, when one should use Total Return based Index instead of Price Index?

I am looking for pros and cons of using either Total Return and/or Price Indexes in a given situation. My initial thought is that if you are a long term investor and being benchmarked against a broad market index, then the portfolio construction and risk management should be based on Total Return Index as you will be collecting dividends while holding the Index. However, if you are a short term investor, then you would probably be looking at Price based Index.

One might perhaps point out that these differences are insignificant. But I guess it depends on many factors, including ones portfolio/investment universe. For example, by looking at Swiss and Japanese equity market indexes, we can observe the following:

[image]

I would appreciate all the comments and resources. Thank you.

Comment: The differences aren't insignificant at all, but even your short term argument doesn't make sense to me.  For anything investment-related, I'd expect you'd use total returns unless you were simply explicitly looking to exclude divs for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Any reference would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the period here, daily, weekly, monthly,...returns ?

Comment: Weekly returns from 2007 to present.

Comment: Very strange: there was a week when one of the markets (SMI?) was down almost 25%. During this week the other market (Nikkei?) was down more than 20% on a price only basis, but up more than 10% on a total return basis. (If I am looking at it right). How can this be.

Comment: ah, there was an error in the formula that pulls price from a system. Now I updated the plots, there is not much difference between Total Return vs Price Index based returns.

Comment: Very good, now it looks OK to me. Not much difference between the two graphs.